# cmd /C doesn't work in Rust when command includes spaces

Tags: windows, rust, command-prompt

I want to run this command from a Rust program:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

In cmd, this works.

```
cmd /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://stackoverflow.com/""
```

In C#, this works.

```
var comm = @"""""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" ""https://stackoverflow.com/""""";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/C " + comm);
```

In Rust, this doesn't work.

```
let comm = r#"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://stackoverflow.com/"""#;
let output = Command::new("cmd")
    .args(&["/C", comm])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```

I get a following error.

```
The network path was not found.
```

However, it works when `comm` is `echo hello`.

I tried two additional ways:

1. This

   ```
   let comm = r#"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/"#;
   ```

   is

   ```
   'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   ```
2. This

   ```
   let comm = r#""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/""#;
   ```

   is

   ```
   '\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   ```

Comment: Chrome is probably in the path so you just need to use `chrome` to run it. And what if the user doesn't like chrome?

Comment: In my environment, `chrome` is not in path. Actually, `comm` is a value which is input by user.

Comment: Rust doesn't just concatenate arguments together, it quotes them for you.  Have you tried it *without* the extra set of quotes around the argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29494). Unfortunately, the Windows rules for escaping arguments are non-trivial and hard to get right.

This code:

```
let comm = r#""C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://stackoverflow.com/"#;
let mut cmd = Command::new("cmd");
cmd.arg("/c");
cmd.arg(comm);
```

Executes this:

```
"cmd" "/c" "\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Unfortunately, the inner quotes have been escaped, although in this case they should not have been.

---

As a workaround, in many cases, you don't actually need to use `cmd`. In those cases, it's much more sensible to directly execute the process instead:

```
let output = Command::new(r#"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"#)
    .args(&["https://stackoverflow.com/"])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, you will only need `cmd /C` to run `cmd` builtins, such as `dir` and the like, or lines of batch script. (if you have a batch *file*, you can run that directly, AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to a similar situation:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::thread;
use std::time;

fn main() {
    let child = Command::new("netsh")
        .arg("advfirewall")
        .arg("firewall")
        .arg("add")
        .arg("rule")
        .arg(r#"name="something2""#)
        .arg("dir=in")
        .arg("action=allow")
        .arg("protocol=TCP")
        .arg("localport=12006")
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed");
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::new(10, 0));
    println!("done");
    let output = child.stdout;
    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

This deals with the command line prompt

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="something2" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=12006
```